# Create a has_one association Error, mass-assign

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I put this in

order.rb

```
  has_one :adress
```

adress.rb

```
belongs_to :order
```

and in form to create one order i put this:

```
<td><%= order.select :adress_id,Adress.all.map { |a| [a.name,a.id] }%></td>
```

but when i try create appear this

Can't mass-assign protected attributes: adress

I dont undertand because appear this, someone solution please, im try put the :adress in order model but have this error:

```
Adress(#2220351840) expected, got String(#2207089660)
```

is a association so sample how i make this please

Comment: Mass assignment is a serious security issues you should avoid it at any cause refer [Ruby on Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#mass-assignment) to countermeasure it

Comment: By looking at your code it seems you are violating MVC pattern here, you should never access a Model directly from the view

Answer (score 0):

Add `attr_accessible :adress` to your model.

Comment: in my post i talk what happening when i put this.

Answer (score 0):

Try:
attr_accessible :adress_attributes in your order model.

If you are using nested has_one association, add,

accepts_nested_attributes_for :adress, :update_only => true

Hope this helps.